# JSF inputText next to selectItem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to display p:inputText next to f:selectItem and get result like on picture below:
[image]

With my code:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="s1" value="#{myBean.selectedValues}" layout="pageDirection" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="value 1" itemValue="v1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="value 2" itemValue="v2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="value 3" itemValue="v3" />
    <p:inputText id="input1" value="#{myBean.input1Value}" />

</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

inputText has been displayed before selectItems:

[image]

I have tried also put inputText into selectItem tag, but result was the same.

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="value 3" itemValue="v3">
    <p:inputText id="input1" value="#{myBean.input1Value}" />
</f:selectItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `p:panelGrid` with `columns="2"`

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">  
    <p:selectManyCheckbox....
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    <p:inputText id="input1" value="#{myBean.input1Value}" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Take a look at other examples [Primefaces PanelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf)